Ordering of solutions of NSolve
I want to compute the solution to an equation with a parameter. It turns out that this solution is a sextic polynomial and mathematica outputs the solutions in a root form. Here's my code
Δ[r] = r^2 + a^2 - 2*M*r;
λ[r] = a + r/a*(r - 2*Δ[r]/(r - M));
η[r] = r^3*(4*a^2*M - r*(r - 3*M)^2)/(a^2*(r - M)^2);

tempsol = r /. NSolve[p == (λ[r]^2/η[r])^-1 /. {a -> 0.99, M -> 1}, r];

Plot[tempsol, {p, -2, 13}]


From this I want to extract the solutions for positive $p$ which are larger than $1$, as I need these for other expressions. These are basically the two continuous parts in orange and blue. However, close to $p=0$, mathematica jumps between the solutions because of the ordering NSolve uses. Is there a way to extract the solutions "continuously"?
I already had a look at this link. However, the solution here just helps for plotting.
Edit: Using the strategy in the first answer does not seem to help, as in my further computation, the region where the solution jumps cannot be plotted.
HTilde = Simplify[(2 a L M r[L, U] + Sqrt[r[L, U] (a^2 + r[L, U] (-2 M + r[L, U])) (U r[L, U]^3 - a^2 (L^2 - U) (2 M + r[L, U]))])/(r[L, U]^4 + a^2 r[L, U] (2 M + r[L, U])) /. r[L, U] -> r /. L -> \[Lambda] H /. U -> H^2 (\[Eta] + \[Lambda]^2) /. H -> Abs[H]]

\[Delta]\[Alpha]1 = -\[Lambda] (1 - HTilde / Abs[H]) /. r -> sol[[1]] /. p -> \[Eta]/\[Lambda]^2 /. {\[Eta] -> \[Beta]^2, \[Lambda] -> -\\[Alpha]} /. {a -> 0.99, M -> 1};

DensityPlot[\[Delta]\[Alpha]1, {\[Alpha], -8, 0}, {\[Beta], 0, 8},PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"SolarColors", "Reverse"}], PlotPoints -> 10, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, #3 &}, Mesh -> {Range[-10, 10, 0.5], Range[-10, 10, 0.5]}, MeshStyle -> Opacity[0.3,Black], ClippingStyle -> Automatic]

The plot with one region clearly not being evaluated is given below.


Are you OK with piecewise definitions?

as long as it gives correct results for small p when plugging the solution into subsequent expressions

$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Δ[r] = r^2 + a^2 - 2*M*r;
λ[r] = a + r/a*(r - 2*Δ[r]/(r - M));
η[r] = r^3*(4*a^2*M - r*(r - 3*M)^2)/(a^2*(r - M)^2);

tempsol = 
  SolveValues[{p == (λ[r]^2/η[r])^-1 /. {a -> 99/100, 
      M -> 1}, p > 0, r > 1}, r];

sol = {Piecewise[List @@@ tempsol[[{1, 3}]]], 
   Piecewise[List @@@ tempsol[[{2, 4}]]]};

Plot[sol, {p, 0, 13}]


EDIT:
HTilde = Simplify[(2  a  L  M  r[L, U] + 
          Sqrt[r[L, 
             U]  (a^2 + r[L, U]  (-2  M + r[L, U]))  (U  r[L, U]^3 - 
              a^2  (L^2 - U)  (2  M + r[L, U]))])/(r[L, U]^4 + 
          a^2  r[L, U]  (2  M + r[L, U])) /. r[L, U] -> r /. 
      L -> λ  H /. U -> H^2  (η + λ^2) /. H -> Abs[H]];

δα1 = -λ  (1 - HTilde/Abs[H]) /. r -> sol[[1]] /. 
     p -> η/λ^2 /. {η -> β^2, λ -> -α} /. {a -> 99/100, M -> 1};

DensityPlot[δα1, {α, -8, 0}, {β, 0, 8},
 PlotLegends -> Automatic,
 ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"SolarColors", "Reverse"}],
 PlotPoints -> 25,
 MaxRecursion -> 3,
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, #3 &},
 Mesh -> {Range[-10, 10, 0.5], Range[-10, 10, 0.5]},
 MeshStyle -> Opacity[0.3, Black],
 ClippingStyle -> Automatic,
 Exclusions -> None]



I unfortunately only have mathematica 12, which doesn't have SolveValues as a function. Is there another way to do this?

r /. Solve[…] will give the same result.

This again works nicely to plot these parts, but using them in further calculations doesn't seem to work. See my edit above.

Works for me. See edit.

I'm sorry but I copy-pasted your code and I still get the same unevaluated region. Could it be an issue with the version of mathematica I am using?

Yes the version makes a difference. It works in v12.0.0 on a Mac if in the plot you change the range of \[Alpha] to {\[Alpha], -8, -10^-6}, i.e., avoid 0

Wonderful! This works. Thank you a bunch for the help!

One way to go at this is to determine where these root functions cross. That can be done by finding zeros of the discriminant polynomial. For that we first need to get a polynomial. I use exact values so that Together will behave.
delta[r] = r^2 + a^2 - 2*M*r;
lambda[r] = a + r/a*(r - 2*delta[r]/(r - M));
nu[r] = r^3*(4*a^2*M - r*(r - 3*M)^2)/(a^2*(r - M)^2);
poly = Numerator[
  Together[(lambda[r]^2/nu[r])^-1 - p /. {a -> 99/100, M -> 1}]]

(* Out[201]= -96059601 p - 192119202 p r + 492000399 p r^2 + 
 392040000 r^3 + 392040000 p r^3 - 900000000 r^4 - 1096020000 p r^4 + 
 600000000 r^5 + 600000000 p r^5 - 100000000 r^6 - 100000000 p r^6 *)

Next we compute the solutions and also the zeros of the discriminant of poly with respect to r.
rts = Solve[poly == 0, r];
rtsV = r /. rts;
dpoly = Discriminant[poly, r]

(* Out[197]= \
1393789027415502113641834611781759672320000000000000000000000000000 \
(-3557763000000000000 p^2 + 9626512203100000000 p^3 + 
   15625948562800000000 p^4 - 3472793096363850000 p^5 + 
   4110172748122553347 p^6 + 10024639204186403347 p^7) *)

Determine values of p where the solution is 1.
oneSol = Solve[poly == 0 /. r -> 1, p]
rtsV /. oneSol // N

(* Out[204]= {{p -> -(10000/199)}}

Out[205]= {{-0.441971, -0.385892, 0.962187, 1., 2.43284 - 0.231795 I, 
  2.43284 + 0.231795 I}} *)

So there is only one point where a root function goes from less to greater than 1, and it is the fourth of the root functions.
Find the zeros of the discriminant and then choose evaluation points between them to see which root functions might be greater than 1 in the respective regions (between discriminant zeros, that is).
pCrossings = 
  Sort[Union@
    Select[SolveValues[dpoly == 0, p], Element[#, Reals] &]];
testvals = 
  Join[{pCrossings[[1]] - 1}, 
   Most[pCrossings] + 
    Differences[pCrossings]/2, {pCrossings[[-1]] + 1}];
pCrossings // N
testvals // N

(* Out[210]= {-1., -0.964972, 0., 0.261643}

Out[211]= {-2., -0.982486, -0.482486, 0.130821, 1.26164} *)

Now we evaluate each root function at these test points, and keep the ones in each region that exceed 1 at the test points. We show the root numbers for each region.
rootvals = 
  Table[Select[rtsV, 
    With[{tval = (# /. p -> testval)}, 
      Element[tval, Reals] && tval >= 1] &], {testval, testvals}];
Map[#[[All, -1]] &, rootvals]

(* Out[229]= {{4}, {5, 6}, {3, 4}, {3, 4}, {1, 2}} *)

Recall that the fourth root is only valid for p>=-10000/199. With this knowledge, we determine that these are the desired roots for the regions indicated below. I remark that one could merge the third and fourth intervals since the relevant root numbers are the same.
Partition[Join[p /. oneSol, pCrossings, {Infinity}], 2, 1] // N

(* Out[232]= {{-50.2513, -1.}, {-1., -0.964972}, {-0.964972, 0.}, {0., 
  0.261643}, {0.261643, \[Infinity]}}

Also note that the second interval on the left is quite small. If you want to visualize the root jumping taking place around there, run this.
tempsol = 
  r /. NSolve[p == (lambda[r]^2/nu[r])^-1 /. {a -> 0.99, M -> 1}, r];
Plot[tempsol, {p, -1.05, -.92}, PlotRange -> {-4, 20}]

